# Show more sites when there is room in new footer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, footer, network-sites

In the new footer, when I click "Science", it expands and shows me a new list of 11 items. It also shows me a more button containing "more(16)". This button, however, seems meaningless, since there is lot more space to show all the remaining items.

Why not show all the items in the footer itself if there is enough room?

The "more" button is correctly organized in the "Technology" section, but it does not seem necessary in the other sections.

Answer (score 13):

We don't include beta sites in the footer on graduated sites, and we don't plan to ever do so. The "more" link will get you to a list which *includes* beta sites which are otherwise not included in the current list in the footer, for those who are interested in participating on those sites.

Being included in the footer on the graduated sites is a privilege reserved for graduated sites only.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind not showing the beta sites in the footer, but I don't think that changes the fact that people who haven't seen this answer are still going to think "Why didn't they just include those links as well? There's enough room..." What about adjusting the footer UI to hint at a reason why the additional links weren't included? I've posted one suggestion with this in mind: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351478/892536, I'd be interested in hearing your thoughts on it.